# 400 No required SSL certificate was sent in Kubernetes K8s

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

I have an application on K8 cluster's pod. While that application invokes the external url, i got an exception "400 No required SSL certificate was sent". I am not sure where to install this cert? Please guide me through.

Well, before I was using Wildfly so the cert was imported in key-store but on K8s, I am not sure where to import the cert? I was expecting the application should call the external url and return 200 instead of this exception "400 No required SSL certificate was sent"